# How to focus on multiple windows

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on selenium using ruby.
Is there any way to focus on a new window from an application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Ruby, but this what you can do in JAVA. See if you can implement similar logic in RUBY.

```
String  parentHandle= driver.getWindowHandle();//Return parent window handle

    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }              

    driver.close(); // close newly opened window 
    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle); // switch back to the parent window
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot leave comments, or else I would point you to both of these websites:

API examples: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp -> ruby option

API docs:     http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Window.html 
              http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html

Here is a direct translation of the code by abhijeet in case you are wondering how it may look like in ruby.

```
parent_handle = driver.window_handle

driver.window_handles.each do |handle|
   driver.switch_to.window handle
end             

driver.close
driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
```